# Regular Expression to end of line

Tags: regex, delphi

I'd like to find commented lines within a string using regular expressions. I tried the following but it gives me everything after the first `//`.

Why?

```
program Project1;

uses
  RegularExpressions;

var
  Text: string;
  Pattern: string;
  RegEx: TRegEx;
  Match: TMatch;
begin
  Text := 'Hello' + #13#10
    + '// Test' + #13#10
    + 'Text' + #13#10;

  Pattern := '//[^$]*$';

  RegEx := TRegEx.Create(Pattern, [roCompiled, roMultiLine]);
  Match := RegEx.Match(Text);
  if (Match.Success) then
  begin
    Match.Index; // 8 -> Expected
    Match.Length; // 15 -> I would like to have 9
  end;
end.
```

Comment: You can tell it to match at line breaks with `(?m)` at the beginning of your pattern.

Comment: If you think there is anything we can help, just let us know via  a comment below our answers.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use the following syntax in your regex: `[^$]*`

This means taking all characters that are not dollar `$` 0 to N times (including `EOL` character) what causes your regex to take the whole string.

Use that regex instead:

```
 Pattern := '//[^\r\n]*'
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
Pattern := '//.*';
```

You may even remove the `roMultiLine` option as you do not need to specify the end of line, `.*` will match 0+ chars other than line breaks, practically matcing any line to its end from the current position (here, after `//`).